# Xorg works only when bbswitch is ON?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, bumblebee, asus, skylake

I've got a weird problem.
I installed bumblebee and when I start Xorg with `startx` it freezes the system completely (cannot switch tty or REISUB). But, when I use bbswitch to turn my dedicated graphics card ON `startx` **does** work and, seeing the differences in fps when running `glxspheres64` and `optirun glxspheres64`, it looks like bumblebee does work correctly.

I thought this should work even when bbswitch is OFF because bumblebee will start the dedicated graphics when necessary?

My system:

- Model: Asus N551VW
- OS: Arch
- CPU: Intel i7 6700HQ
- Dedicated: Nvidia 960m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it appears to be related to both bumblebee and the Nvidia driver. See also [this](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/699) Bumblebee issue.

When Bumblebee wants to turn off the Nvidia card, it will try to run `rmmod nvidia`. But when I run this command Arch says it cannot unload this module because it is used by `nvidia_modeset`. Apparently, this new module was added recently to the Nvidia driver and causes Bumblebee to lock up the system when starting startx (because he cannot turn off the Nvidia card).

So currently, there is no solution, but when Bumblebee 4.0 releases there probably will be one.